# "javax.persistence.SynchronizationType"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to connect to Oracle data base using JPA through a Spring Boot Application. I initially got the error saying

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType
```

I did a search on how to recitify the same and found that o resolve the same I should use version from 2.1.0 for the javax.persistence dependency.

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Upon changing the same, the error is resolved, but I am getting another error now:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.persistence.SynchronizationType"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <groupId>com.in28minutes</groupId>
    <artifactId>in28Minutes-first-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>

<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>

    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    </exclusion>

</exclusions> 


</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
             <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>



        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>






      <!-- Java 8 = JAX-B Version 2.2.8  added to correct missing entity manager error-->
     <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>




              <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>



            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/</path>
                        <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

My application class:

```
package com.myfirst.classes.from.db;


import java.util.Date;

//import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
//import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

//import com.example.database.databasejdbcdemo.SpringDataDemoApplication;


/*@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,
         HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })*/

//@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.myfirst.classes.from.db")
@ComponentScan("com.myfirst.classes.from.db")
@SpringBootApplication


public class SpringDataDemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    //private org.slf4j.Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    PersonSpringDataRepository repository ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("hello");
        //logger.info("Person with ID 10002 ->{}",repository.findById(10002));
        //logger.info("Updating person with ID 10002 ->{}",repository.save(new Person(10002,"Kunjol","Home",new Date())));
        //logger.info("Person with ID 10002 ->{}",repository.findById(10002));
        //logger.info("Inserting a new person now ->{}",repository.save(new Person(10007,"Karthik","Home",new Date())));
        //logger.info("Person with ID 10007 ->{}",repository.findByName("Karthik"));
    //repository.deleteById(10001);
    //logger.info("Person with ID 10001 ->{}",repository.findById(10001));

    }

}
```

PersonSpringDataRepository.java

```
package com.myfirst.classes.from.db;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
@Transactional

public interface PersonSpringDataRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,Integer> {


}
```

And the Person.java

```
package com.myfirst.classes.from.db;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Entity
@Table(name="person")

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("oracle")

public class Person {

//  private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
//  @Bean
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private Date birth_date;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public Date getBirth_date() {
        return birth_date;
    }
    public void setBirth_date(Date birth_date) {
        this.birth_date = birth_date;
    }
    public Person(int id, String name, String location, Date birth_date) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.birth_date = birth_date;
    }

    public Person( String name, String location, Date birth_date) {
        super();

        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.birth_date = birth_date;
    }

    public  Person()
    {
        //By default, Spring will try to instantiate beans by calling a default (no-arg) constructor.
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", location=" + location + ", birth_date=" + birth_date + "]";
    }
}
```

What could be the possible reason for the issue? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error now. The root cause is that eclipselink jar contains class javax.persistence.SynchronizationType, but it also brings another dependency (jakarta.persistence) which also contains the same class - and the one that actually gets used is from other jar (and signed by other cert) than the rest of the package.

With that said, I could not find a straight solution for this. IMO the problem is in eclipselink bringing the same class twice and until that is fixed, we can only look for workarounds.

EDIT: Here is another thread which has a solution (exclude JPA API from eclipselink and bring in another one which isn't signed)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up excluding jakarta.persistence in favor of hibernate-jpa-2.1-api jar and that worked!

Until, EL team becomes active and respond to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=549240